# Work with associations on server side; table relationships

Tags: extjs, associations

I need to do something like this, but on the server side.
http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-associations

My code (when I select one Customers grid row):

```
selectionchange: function(sm, grid, value, selected, eOpts) {

    var storeCustomers = grid.getStore();

    var gridOrders = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridOrdersItemId')[0];
    var storeOrders = gridOrders.getStore();        

    var id_customers = storeCustomers.findRecord('id_customers', value); //It does not work; return null

    console.log(id_customers ); //null
    console.log(value); //undefined

    storeOrders.proxy.extraParams = {
            'id_customers': id_customers
    },

    storeOrders.load();
```

}

For some reason I can not get the value of id_customers when I select a grid record. the result is null.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edited: 06-07-2015

```
selectionchange: function(sm, grid, record, value, selected, eOpts) {

    var storeCustomers = grid.getStore();

    var gridOrders = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridOrdersItemId')[0];
    var storeOrders = gridOrders.getStore();        

   var records = grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected(record);

    storeOrders.proxy.extraParams = {
            'id_customers': records.get('id_customers')
    },

    storeOrders.load();
```

}

Comment: The problem you are facing ("can not get the value of id_customers") has no relevance to server side coding. Also you are not actually using associations in the quoted code.

Comment: Sorry !. It was the best way I found to explain the context of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding this:

> For some reason I can not get the value of id_customers when I select
>   a grid record. the result is null.

here is a possible solution:

```js
selectionchange: function(grid, records) {
    var storeOrders = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridOrdersItemId')[0]
                                        .getStore();
    storeOrders.proxy.extraParams = {
            'id_customers': records[0].get('id_customers')
    },
    storeOrders.load();
}
```

Comment: Thanks DrakeES. records [0] is not working in my case. Any idea what could be ?.I edited my question with a solution that works.

Comment: According to [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-selectionchange), the second variable passed to `selectionchange` event handler (i.e. `records` in the proposed solution) already contains the selection, i.e. an array of selected records. Can you `console.log(records)` to see if any records are there?

Comment: It did not work because in my code, 'records' was not exactly in the second position (second variable passed to selectionchange event handler ). Now it works. Thanks again DrakeES.